# How to check a global variable from loop in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a method that delete some fingers print from sensor, First I loaded the list of it's id from database, then I create write command (write on serial port) to delete each one with that ID : `DeleteFP(int id)`
the data is correct and write it on my port, but I want to create a loop to delete all finger prints that I send the ids, so I create a simple loop:

```
bool FP::DeleteFP(int id)
{
    ClearTemplate(id);//write on port to clear dada
    clearTmpStatus=false;//if this id deleted then it make true// global variable

    int t=0;
    do
    {
      t++;
      if(checkDelFP())
      {
          clearTmpStatus=false;
          qDebug()<<"t is: "<<t<<"clear status is"<<clearTmpStatus;
          return true;
      }
      if(/*clearTmpStatus ||*/ t==1000)
      {
          qDebug()<<"t is: "<<t<<"clear status is"<<clearTmpStatus;
          return false;
      }

    }while(1);
    return clearTmpStatus;
}

bool FP::checkDelFP()
{
  if(clearTmpStatus )
  {
      qDebug()<<"clear status is"<<clearTmpStatus;
      FPCancel();
  }
}
```

the read method (from serial port) is in a thread, when I call delete finger print method, it sends delete command to finger print device and then device responses to success delete in my thread and change the global variable `clearTmpStatus` from false to true,I used the loop to check the value of `clearTmpStatus` , I think the GUI stop and the loop call another function to check `clearTmpStatus` and when it changed the loop get the change, but when the loop works, the change not affect, after loop stops and finished  the changing is happen. the problem is here , How can I check the global variable change after the thread change the value of it? Is there any solution?

Comment: What is `ListOfId`? How can you use it as both an integer as an array?

Comment: Using global variable in multi-threading in a such way looks strange and unsafe. Did you consider changing the approach?

Comment: `ListOfId` is the list of my finger prints id saved in my database to manage them (for delete or updating), it just a list of integer (it is sample code the real code is not here now)

Comment: @VolAnd, give me another approach , if you have. I become happy

Comment: When you say that `ListOfId` is "just a list of integer", what do you mean by that? Is it a homegrown linked list of structures? Is it a `std::list`? Is it a `std::vector`? Is it an array?

Comment: its like this: `QStringList listofid=database->getlistofid(10).split(',');` and convert each number from string format to int format with this code : `deletefp(listofid.at(i).toint());` I told you I don't have the exact code right now. I think this is the real code that I wrote it in my program

Comment: Then may I suggest you take a pause, try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and come back here with that? Because if `ListOfId` is a [`QStringList`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html) then the code you show us won't even build. Having a n [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is very important for us to be able to really help you. And unless you ask about build-errors (which you don't) then having the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) actually *build* is also important.

Comment: thanks for reply, but I dont have any errors, I need a solution to solve the problem.I told my read port function is in thread and when get success change the global variable, how can  I check my global variable and stop gui ? just this I dont need to correct my code (because I think I should change whole of my code)

Answer (score 1):

The correct ways of reading a global variable in `C++11` onwards, is to read them through `std::atomic`.

The compiler ensures that changes are properly propagated through to the various parts of the program.

Before `C++11`, it was necessary to create the variable as `volatile`.  This stopped the compiler creating a cache of the value.

It is important to make the compiler realize that the value can change outside of any flow it is running.

Comment: really thanks for your answer, I I understand you mean I should use `volatile` for my global variable, this keyword says the compiler check the global variable outside of the loop if it changes?Is it?

Comment: this is my output:`list is: ("1", "2", "")__del finger id is 1__
port write :  "55aa05010200010000000000000000000000000000000801" *******   success write len is :  24 
=====================
 t is:  1000 clear status is false 
===================== 
_______READ byte_________
 "aa5505010400000001000000000000000000000000000a01" ` after loop finished, the read byte success show(READ byte is in thread)